# How to automate an SSH login with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ssh

At my place of work we have to use SSH via CMD to access our Cisco switches. I'd like to write a batch file to semi-automate the login process so that all we need to do is type in the desired switch name and our password. We can't use PUTTY, Cisco Analyser, SSH keys, expect etc., our only allowed method is CMD (it's baffled us too!)

I'm currently the only one of us around and my knowledge on this is not up to par for the job, hence asking you fine folks for a bit of help!

What I'd like the script to do is firstly ask which switch I would like to connect to, use that as a variable to fill in the command at which point the switch will ask for the password to validate access.

The base command for the connection is:

```
ssh <account-name>@<switch-name(FQDN)>
```

So far my script reads as:

```
@echo off
title SSH Switch Access
echo Please enter destination switch name...
```

As I said, I'm relatively new to writing scripts as I hail from a hardware background so never really had to use them much or had others around that could do it, as much as I'd like to learn how to do this on my own there's a hell of a lot to learn and it'll take me a long while to get conversant enough to do it alone.

Comment: The switch name would obviously change depending on which one we needed to connected to so I'm hoping that can be used as a variable to complete the SSH command.  The account name would be fixed as I'd just modify it in the .bat and give each of my colleagues a copy with their account name in it instead of mine.  And it would be manual password entry, not ssh-keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example. You can list the devices as comma separated values in a variable. Simply run a for loop through them and use the `choice` command to assign a number to hostname. You simply press the keyboard number to make the connection.

Because only 9 numeric values can be used (unless you use non numerical) I simply created a next function where you can use option 9 to show the next set. You can use a similar approach to add a previous, if you'd like. Simply update your device list and username.

```
@echo off & cls & title SSH Switch Access
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set myuser=USERNAME
set "switchList=switch-1,switch-2,switch-3,switch-4,switch-5,switch-6,switch-7,switch-8,switch-9,switch-10,switch-11,switch-12,switch-13,switch-14,switch-15,switch-16,switch-17,switch-18,switch-19,switch-20"
for %%i in (%switchList%) do (
   set /a cnt+=1
   set "dev[!cnt!]=%%i"
   call echo !cnt!. %%dev[!cnt!]%%
   set chosen=!chosen!!cnt!
   if !cnt! equ 8 (
      set /a cnt+=1
      set "dev[9]=Next"
      call echo !cnt!. %%dev[!cnt!]%%
      set chosen=!chosen!!cnt!
      call :list
      if !selected! neq 9 goto :EOF
      cls
      set /a cnt=0
      set chosen=
   )
)

:list
echo(
choice /c %chosen% /m "Select destination switch:"
if not %errorlevel% equ 9 ssh %myuser%@!dev[%errorlevel%]!
set "selected=%errorlevel%"
if not %errorlevel% equ 9 goto :EOF
```

Note, if you have a huge list of devices, you can either add the devices to a file and read from the file. Again, this might mean a lot of skipping pages to find your device, in that case, it is much simpler to just run the below and type the switch name on request:

```
@echo off
set myuser=USERNAME
set /p "switch=Please enter destination switch name : "
ssh.exe %myuser%@%switch%
```

**Edit**: Do not name your script the same as any executable in path. i.e. in this instance, do not name it `ssh.bat` or `ssh.cmd`.

Reason for this being; `cmd.exe` will always first check if the basename you supplied is available in the current directory, if not, will it seatch your `%path%` variable for the basename and extentions in order as specified by `%pathext%`

I this case, `ssh.bat` or `ssh.cmd` exists in the current directory. When you paunch the script will it then run `ssh.bat user@switch` instead.
Rename your script to `my_ssh.bat` or similar and also change the `ssh` in the script to `ssh.exe` to ensure the script does not launch itself.

Comment: The last script is exactly what i was after, thank you!  However, after entering the switch name it just asks me to enter the switch name again.

Comment: Not possible,  @Callidon. Please tell me what you have named your script?

Comment: @Callidon It is a very bad idea to name a batch file like an executable like `ssh.exe`. Give your batch file a different name than `ssh.cmd` (batch file processed by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe`) or `ssh.bat` (batch file with file extension as on MS-DOS, Windows 95/98/ME and interpreted by `COMMAND.COM` on these operating systems). `SwitchLogin.cmd` would be a good name for the batch file. See also: [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Comment: @Callidon It would be further advisable to reference the executable `ssh` in the batch file with file name + file extension, i.e. with `ssh.exe` instead of just `ssh`. Best would be the usage of the fully qualified file name of this executable which is `%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`. Please note further that `ssh.exe` exists only as 64-bit application. If the batch file is processed for some reason by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`, the 32-bit *Windows Command Processor* would fail to find `ssh.exe` even on using the fully qualified file name.

Comment: @Callidon The solution would be `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe (set "SSHEXE=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe") else set "SSHEXE=%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"` and there is used next `%SSHEXE% %myuser%@%switch%` for a batch file working also on being interpreted by the 32-bit *Windows Command Processor* on 64-bit Windows. Read the Microsoft documentation about the [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) for more information.

Comment: Hi Mofi, not sure what you're referring to, I'm not naming my batch file as an executable!

Comment: @Gerhard I've named the script ssh.bat and used exactly what you suggested in the smaller code segment at the bottom of your previous reply. I really do appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: @Callidon, nobody said you'd named it `ssh.exe`, the implication was that you'd named it with the basename `ssh`. Your problem is that `ssh` isn't a command. When you use `ssh`, you trigger a series of unnecessary background checks. The first is the system determines if there's a file in the current working directory with the basename `ssh`. If there is, it will next determine if you have a variable named `PATHEXT`, if you have, it'll parse it, in value order, appending each to the basename to see if that matches the full file name. At the first match it runs that file, i.e. `ssh.bat`.

Comment: Simply rename your script to something like `my_ssh.bat` and your problem will be solved @Callidon

Comment: @Gerhard Thank you sir! All working after the name change! Compo, mofi Apologies, i misunderstood what you were explaining, my novice level of scripting is maybe more obvious than i expected!  This is my first experience on Stack and all three of you have been very helpful, even if just to point out my comprehension issues!